# How does added weight of 100kg affect the height of a originally 1m stack of paper

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, weight

Lets say i had a stack of papers, 1 meter tall. Assuming that each paper would be around 0.1mm in thickness, the total number of papers should be 10000. Now, when placing a weight of 100kg on top of said stack, the stack appears to "compress". How could I go about finding how much the height of the stack decreased? And how could i get the original height from the height with the weight on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on a lot of things, not least of which is how "flat" or rumpled the papers actually are and how much air gap on average is between each one. For paper there is probably no better way than doing the experiment and measuring.

For a more *rigid* stack like a stack of metal plates or even plastic or composites (with little or no air gap), you could use the simple linear elastic Hooke's law:

$$F=kx$$

Where force $F$ required to compress the stack a distance of $x$ from its neutral position is given by the stiffness $k$.  For common materials this stiffness can be calculated from the Elastic Modulus $E$ of the material plus the height $L$ and the cross sectional area $A$ of the stack, viz.

$$F= \frac {EA}{L} x  $$

Comment: My office store sells ten reams of printer paper (5k sheets) in a box for about fifty dollars. Open the box, put the two stacks of five reams on top of each other, then hop your 50 kg self up on top of it. For the full College Physics Major experience, you could do the experiment inside the office store without even buying the paper. There are meter sticks the next aisle over. Any correction for the different type of paper which wraps the individual reams is left as an exercise. Beware also that not all paper is equal: porous Fancy Art Vellum is probably squashier than Cheapest Copier Paper.